# Couldn't access Kubernetes dashboard on Google Cloud

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I am following the instructions as given [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/gce/).

I used the following command to get a running cluster, in gcloud console I typed: `curl -sS https://get.k8s.io | bash` as described in the link, after that, I ran the command `kubectl cluster-info` from that I got:

```
kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://35.188.109.36/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-
system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
```

but when I go to that url from firefox, the message that comes is:

```
User "system:anonymous" cannot proxy services in the namespace 
"kube-system".: "No policy matched."
```

Expected behavior: Should ask for an admin name and password to connect to the dashboard.

Comment: what version of kubernetes your using? this document may be  < 1.5,  in 1.6    they enabled RBAC, we can can't access like this.

Comment: @sfgroups its 1.6.4 version, so how do I access the dashboard anyways ?

Comment: you can look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44411940/how-to-generate-the-configuration-to-connect-to-a-remote-kubernetes-host/44412468#44412468

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you did not use GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) which provides the dashboard add-on installed out of the box?

In your case, simply:

- the kubernetes-dashboard addon might not be installed (but logs say so, so I think this is not the problem)
- network configuration that makes `kubectl proxy` work might not be there
- the `curl .. | sh` script you used probably did not configure the authentication properly.

I recommend using GKE as this works out of the box. You can find documentation here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/oss-ui

---

If you still want to use GCE, I recommend running `kubectl proxy` on your workstation (not your kubernetes nodes) and visiting `http://127.0.0.1:8001/ui` on your browser to see if it works.

If you get an error about not having enough permissions, you might be using a Kubernetes version new enough that enforces RBAC policies on pods like dashboard which access the API. You can grant those permissions by running:

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin  \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin  \
  --serviceaccount=kube-system:default
```

---

I also recommend trying out GKE UI in Google Cloud Console: https://console.cloud.google.com/kubernetes

Comment: Thanks for the alternative (authentic) way. GKE works awesome. I didn't know about GKE until then.

Comment: If it's the correct answer please consider marking as such.

Comment: I must when I try the procedure you stated - works correctly. Currently much busy..will try out soon and let you know about that by marking :)

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is being deprecated. We need to use Cloud Console dashboards, [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/).

[Official Message](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards):

> The open source Kubernetes Dashboard addon is deprecated for clusters on GKE and will be removed as an option in version 1.15. It is recommended to use the alternative Cloud Console dashboards described on [this page](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards).

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to deploy k8s on Google Compute Engine it is still possible to access the dashboard. True if the instructions  at [kubernetes.io/docs/setup/](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/) are followed, you will receive 403's as described.

Firstly you need to deploy a 'dashboard deployment' run this command;

`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.0.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml`

Once created (in the kube-system namespace btw), create a clusterrolebinding with this command;

`kubectl create clusterrolebinding add-on-cluster-admin    --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kube-system:default`

Run the following to get a token;
`kubectl config view | grep token`

Next run a kubectl proxy with command;
`kubectl proxy`

You will now be able to access the dashboard at uri below.
You will need to pass the token from above to authenticate, and that's it...

http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

Answer (score -5):

you can run `kubectl proxy` locally and access it at http://localhost:8001/ui

Comment: Will it work in case I am using kubernetes in google compute engine ?

Comment: The original answer is related to Google Container Engine, therefore `kubectl proxy` won't work.