# Access to kubernetes dashboard using gcloud

Tags: kubernetes, devops, gcloud, kubernetes-dashboard

Using gcloud I have created a stand cluster.

When I run the command `kubectl cluster-info` I have this output:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://<cluster-ip>
GLBCDefaultBackend is running at https://<cluster-ip>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/default-http-backend:http/proxy
Heapster is running at https://<cluster-ip>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster/proxy
KubeDNS is running at https://<cluster-ip>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy
kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://<cluster-ip>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy
Metrics-server is running at https://<cluster-ip>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:metrics-server:/proxy
```

When I would like to access the dashboard (web ui interface), e.g `kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://<cluster-ip>/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy` I have this error:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"https:kubernetes-dashboard:\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get services/proxy in the namespace \"kube-system\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "https:kubernetes-dashboard:",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

I know there is a lot of questions around this kind of issue concerning the kubernetes dashboard, but I don't find the right to properly access and connect throughthe web ui from gcloud directly.

Comment: try [these settings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47318219/10727144) and check if you can access the dashboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run first `kubectl proxy` in order to access the kubernetes dashboard as peer the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/#accessing-the-dashboard-ui).
After that you can provide the bearer token or Kubeconfig file, see this documentation on hoe to get [Bearer Token](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Access-control#bearer-token).

Another option to get the full access to your GKE dashboard see below:

```
gcloud get-credentials <GKE cluster name> --zone <zone> --project <project>
gcloud config config-helper --format=json | jq .credential.access_token
```

Copy the Token and use it for full access to all the Dashboard section.